# Text encoding (converting to numeric) based on user-defined rules in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have data in text form that I need to encode/convert to numeric form according to rules I defined. To clarify:

[image]

Need formula for output column so that it compares original text data with text-number encoding rules and returns numeric value of text in each row.

Comment: The *VLOOKUP()* worksheet function does exactly what you want.   See Excel Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C3 and drag down:

```
=INDEX(F$2:F$6,MATCH(A3,E$2:E$6,0))
```